# AngularJs $resource not invoking custom 'GET'

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing, angular-resource

I have created a simple RESTful service in .Net which is hosted [here](http://publicapitest.azurewebsites.net/Help).
I am trying to invoke `getByName` action from my angularjs code.  But, angularjs code is invoking default '`get`' instead of '`getByName`'

AngularJs code:

```
app.factory('UserResourceSvc',function($resource){
    var baseApiUrl = "http://publicapitest.azurewebsites.net/";
    //var baseApiUrl = "http://localhost:92/"
    return $resource( baseApiUrl + 'api/Employee/:id',{id: "@id"},
        { 
            getByName : {method: 'GET', params: {} , isArray: false} 
        }
    );    
});
```

I am invoking below function on button click to trigger API call.

```
 $scope.getByName = function(){
   UserResourceSvc.getByName(function(data){
      debugger;
   })
 }
```

I am getting below error message :

```
angular.js:14794 Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `getByName`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array (Request: GET http://publicapitest.azurewebsites.net/api/Employee)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.7/$resource/badcfg?p0=getByName&p1=object&p2=array&p3=GET&p4=http%3A%2F%2Fpublicapitest.azurewebsites.net%2Fapi%2FEmployee
    at angular.js:116
    at $http.then.response.resource (angular-resource.js:757)
    at processQueue (angular.js:17145)
    at angular.js:17193
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:18331)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18628)
    at done (angular.js:12619)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:12863)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:12780) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
```

When I checked in fiddler call is going to `'http://publicapitest.azurewebsites.net/api/Employee'` instead of `'http://publicapitest.azurewebsites.net/api/Employee/getByName'`

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I haven't used $resource in a long time (I find it easier to just use $http) but I think the custom actions only apply to instances of the items you return from your inital call?  So you could do `UserResourceSvc.get(..)`, then each instance returned will have a `$getByName` function available, so this is probably not the approach you're looking for?

Comment: See the example in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#examples.  The $charge method only applies to instances of items returned from the initial API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify method url as follows:

```
getByName : {method: 'GET', url: baseApiUrl + 'api/Employee/getByName', params: {} , isArray: false}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @lzagkaretos, I was under impression that key name 'getByName' will take care of invoking correct endpoint.  In that case it seems, second parameter to $resource is useless if we want to use custom  REST endpoint ( other than 'get','put','post','delete' )